# C++ program that use macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a problem that use macro and when i compile the result is 11, but i don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_VAL    100
#define START    MAX_VAL-10
#define SQUARE(x)     x * x

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    for(i=START/2; i<MAX_VAL; i++)
    {
        a++;
    }

    cout << "\n " << SQUARE(a+1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perform the macro replacements manually yourself and you will see. Also, you can instruct the compiler to output the preprocessed code, though that's going to be messy.

Comment: Note, since C++ has all sorts of features like template functions, `const`, `constexpr` and more, macros like this aren't really necessary.

Comment: You may want to `cout << a <<  endl;` before the last `cout`

Comment: Hint: How does `SQUARE(a+1)` expand as per your definition? Remember, macros are *dumb*.

Comment: 1. By the end of the loop, `a` is 5. 2. So you see `5 + 1 * 5 + 1` printed, which is 11.

Comment: Another in a long list of reasons to prefer other solutions over macros when possible.

Comment: remove the include and with gcc use `-E` to see output after preprocessing: https://godbolt.org/z/fP8M8W

Comment: Yes, by the end of the loop variable a has the value 5. Also, by the end of the loop the value of variable i has the values : 95, 96, 97, 98, 99. But i don't understand why ? Thank you.

Comment: The code in the last link from @idclev463035818 should answer that. Look at the code in the second pane. it has the loop as `for(i=100 -10/2; i<100; i++)`

Comment: Love them macros.  Evaluate this: `SQUARE("Hello");`